# what makes two same objects performance different?

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, benchmark.js

## source

define two object both with `getter` and `setter`, with the same code

both test with `benchmark.js` in `node v7.3.0`

```
const builtInObject1 = (function (object) {
    let lastA = 1;
    return Object.defineProperties(object, {
        a:{
            get(){
                return lastA
            },
            set(newValue){
                lastA = newValue;
            }
        }
    })
})({});

const builtInObject2 = (function (object) {
    let lastA = 1;
    return Object.defineProperties(object, {
        a:{
            get(){
                return lastA
            },
            set(newValue){
                lastA = newValue;
            }
        }
    })
})({});
```

~ add`es2015`'s`getter/setter`case

```
const builtInObject3 = (function () {
    let lastA = 1;
    return {
        get a(){
            return lastA
        },
        set a(value){
            lastA = value;
        }
    }
})();
```

~

```
const builtInObject4 = (function (object) {
    let last = 1;
    return Object.defineProperties(object, {
        b:{
            get(){
                return last
            },
            set(newValue){
                last = newValue;
            }
        }
    })
})({});

const builtInObject5 = (function (object) {
    let last = 1;
    return Object.defineProperties(object, {
        c:{
            get(){
                return last
            },
            set(newValue){
                last = newValue;
            }
        }
    })
})({});
```

~

```
(new Benchmark.Suite("object-assign-properties"))
    .add("#built-in object1.a getter and setter", function () {
        builtInObject1.a = builtInObject1.a + 1;
    })
    .add("#built-in object2.a getter and setter", function () {
        builtInObject2.a = builtInObject2.a + 1;
    })
    .add("#built-in object3.a es6 getter and setter", function () {
        builtInObject3.a = builtInObject3.a + 1;
    })
    .add("#built-in object4.b getter and setter", function () {
        builtInObject4.b = builtInObject4.b + 1;
    })
    .add("#built-in object5.c getter and setter", function () {
        builtInObject5.c = builtInObject5.c + 1;
    })
    .on('cycle', function(event) {
        console.log(String(event.target));
    })
    .on('complete', function() {
        console.log('Fastest is ' + this.filter('fastest').map('name'));
    })
    .run({ 'async': false });
```

#### result

```
#built-in object1.a getter and setter x 80,459,419 ops/sec ±0.65% (88 runs sampled)
#built-in object2.a getter and setter x 3,967,313 ops/sec ±0.36% (91 runs sampled)
#built-in object3.a es6 getter and setter x 3,982,725 ops/sec ±0.51% (93 runs sampled)
#built-in object4.b getter and setter x 79,608,022 ops/sec ±4.06% (87 runs sampled)
#built-in object5.c getter and setter x 78,849,808 ops/sec ±0.82% (92 runs sampled)
Fastest is #built-in object1.a getter and setter
```

difference between `ops/sec` of these tests result make me confuse

## **Why???**

what makes these differences ?

accroding to [bluebird | Optimization-killers](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Optimization-killers), `object3` would not be optimized, but why `object2` get so slow ??

#### reference ???

- jsperf tests, seems both of two tests run with a optimized code in my browser (osx Chrome Canary 57, CPU:i7), just got `3,800,000` opt/sec

  - https://jsperf.com/what-makes-two-same-objects-performance-different/1
  - https://jsperf.com/what-makes-two-same-objects-performance-different/3

#### related links

- [github/bestiejs/benchmark.js | issue #184](https://github.com/bestiejs/benchmark.js/issues/184)
- [github/nodejs/help | #442](https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/442)

Comment: What if you run the test for `builtInObject2` first?

Comment: .. so why are you asking about the object performance and not about the test suite you are using when performance difference follow the way you organize the tests?

Comment: @zerkms regardless of whether or not it is run first, if define object2 first, then object2 would be faste. whatever test runing first or second ..

Comment: @Soren I'm not sure its javascript behavior or test suite problem.

Comment: @zerkms @Soren if object1 and object2 define setter/getter property with two different name ( like: `object1.a` and `object2.b` ), then the benchmark will the `same` result